# Why does the modal not appear in the center?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, semantic-ui

I'm using a semantic's modal with angular and i'm getting position problem. the thing is, when i pop up the modal, it doesn't show at the right position.

[image]

this is my **html file**

```
<div class="ui modal">
      <div class="header">Header</div>
      sdasdasdasds
</div>
```

this is in **controller.js file**

```
$scope.agregar = function(){

    //$('.ui.modal').modal();
    $('.ui.modal').modal({blurring: true}).modal('show').modal("refresh");
}
```

Comment: Should I point out that the js is not in `<script>` tags, or is that an editing thing?

Comment: Post CSS code also.

Comment: I'm using the semantics' css default files

Comment: The problem is in CSS so try to figure that out.

Comment: @TricksfortheWeb  I'm using Angular's controllers

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply, but your post came as a search result when i was looking for the solution for the same problem.

Some [**portals**](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/3175) say that timeout of 100ms works, but it didn't help me.

I found a workaround for the issue. Not a very good approach but doing refresh twice solved the problem for me.

I was working on angular plus semantic combination and you can see the following snippet :

```
$scope.reviewAppointment = function(appointment) {
    var modal = $('.ui.modal');

    modal.modal('show');
    modal.modal('refresh');
    modal.modal('refresh');

    //rest of the code
}
```

**Following is when refresh was not done**

[image]

**When the refresh was done once**

Better than previous case, but you can still see some extra space above the modal and no space was left at the bottom.

[image]

**When refresh was done twice**

The modal is placed perfectly at the centre. It wouldn't change if you now apply refresh more number of times.

[image]

Hope it helps. But again not a very good approach.